# How would you loop through a list of 100 names to check that a certain entry is not one of those values in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, blacklist

I have a certain input that when the user enters a word in needs to be checked against a list of 100 words. How would I loop through these words the easiest? Should I use a massive array?

Comment: Is this supposed to be for a bad-word filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about case sensitivity or typos, this is the most straight-forward way:

```
$word = 'foo';
$wordList = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', ...);
$wordIsInWordList = in_array($word, $wordList);
```

Comment: what do you mean by typos? typos of the user typing in?

Comment: @chrome Just word variations. If it's just for vanity URLs this should work if you `strtolower($word)`.